# How to create an embedded document from a table using pentaho

Tags: mongodb, pentaho

I have to table student and record, the relationship is a student have many records (one to many).

How I can represent a transformation on pentaho so that I can insert every line in the record table as an embedded document in the student document.

All this is for migrate the tables to mongodb data structure, also It will be nice to have a way to convert the sequence id on the table to the ObjectId BSON type, so in this way I can keep the references relationships too, for other tables relationship by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already done the embedded document creation using this documentation.

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MongoDB+Output

What I miss now is when I want to keep the reference model, migrating the ID to a ObjectID in mongodb.